# Painting Dark Color

Tags: walls, painting, interior

I'm painting a wall with a very dark color, - a black/green, The wall was previously painted white.

I'm using Behr Marquee One Coat.

Problem is that I went over with a brush areas where I saw tiny little white dots, ( *probably due to the roller did not have enough paint* ). Now that it has dried 8+ hours, I can see patches where I went over with the brush.

How do I even out the patches ?

Should I apply another coat over the entire wall ?

Thanks.

Comment: Was the white paint a gloss or semi-gloss ? Sometimes new paint has trouble bonding to gloss or semi-gloss. Also, I find "*one coat paint*" to be mostly a marketing gimmick.

Comment: It might have been semi-gloss. I'm going to try another coat. Thank you for the advice - again!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a second coat. When changing to a very different color, it's almost impossible to do an acceptable job with only one coat, doesn't matter how good the paint is.

Comment: two coats did the trick. I think like Alaska Man said, 'one coat' is a marketing gimmick. Thanks.

Comment: Or - Doesn't matter how good **the manufacturer says** the paint is.

Comment: If you look at some of the quantity allocations for different applications you can see that one coat means going over every area three times.

Comment: @Anh Well, it might work if the surface was primed, and the primer was tinted to be quite close to the topcoat color.  And you sprayed it. And the job was perfect.   I live in the real world, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to go over it again.  And really you will need to do the surrounding area as the brush marks will require a deal of paint to cover.   Just FYI if you go through that same process hit it with a brush then roller over it lightly after.   You can also use the foam brushes.  They do touchups well but they are cheap and drip a lot.

Comment: gotcha. I'm going to give it another coat.

Comment: It is perfectly normal when drastically switching colors on a wall to have to break out a new roller the next day.   Honestly if you do the edges (ceiling/trim) right the first day that is still an A+ job.  Also suggest to people to get a 400W+ worklight when painting.   I know that most home owners don't have one - but they are small and have a lot of uses - checking paint jobs being one.  Wet paint even in a well lit room will shadow and not show until it is dried a bit.